# populating section titles from an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

is this possible to do , or do i have to do it all manually with if statements?

something like

```
return [sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes ...the piece of code that you have written is very much possible... and can implemented that way...